# Clone Root Server into Amazon Cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, debian, clone

i've got an old debian root server, that is hosted at an provider in germany. The maschine is now about 6 years old and i want to move it to a cloud.

the question is if there is an easy way to clone the root server (dd or something else) and use this an amazon (or something else) cloud server.

are there any way's to this or do i have to migrate the whole server to a new instance in the cloud.

thx

Answer (score 0):

Look into this tool http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/ it should do what you're asking.

The first method is to import your VM image using the Amazon EC2 API tools. To get started, simply:

- Download the VM Import Command Line Tools from Amazon EC2 API tools.
- Import the VMDK, VHD or RAW file via the ec2-import-instance API. The import instance task captures the parameters necessary to properly configure the Amazon EC2 instance properties (instance size, availability zone, and security groups) and uploads the disk image into Amazon S3.
- If ec2-import-instance is interrupted or terminates without completing the upload, use ec2-resume-import to resume the upload. The import task will resume where it left off.
- Use the ec2-describe-conversion-tasks command to monitor the import progress and obtain the resulting Amazon EC2 instance ID.
- Once your import task is completed, you can boot the Amazon EC2 instance by specifying its instance ID to the ec2-run-instances API.
- Finally, use the ec2-delete-disk-image command line tool to delete your disk image from Amazon S3.